# Ngrx not working properly with AOT in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, redux, ngrx, angular2-aot

From past couple of days I am trying to use `ngrx` with `AOT`, with `JIT` it works fine, but with AOT it gives this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` in `combineReducers`, I believe its because it's getting undefined as the first parameter, here is my code:

```
// reducer.ts

import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { ActionReducer, ActionReducerMap, combineReducers } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AppStore } from './AppStore';
import { FormCreate, FormList, FormTemplates } from './forms';

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppStore> = {
    formCreate: FormCreate,
    formList: FormList,
    formTemplates: FormTemplates
};

export const reducerToken = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<AppStore>>('Registered Reducers');

export const reducerProvider = [
    { provide: reducerToken, useValue: reducers },
];


// app.module.ts
// I tried all below 3 versions, but all gives same error
imports: [
    // Version 1
    StoreModule.forRoot(Object.assign(reducerToken, reducers)),
    // Version 2
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducerToken),
    // Version 3
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
],
providers: [
    reducerProvider
]
```

Above was the one way of doing using `InjectionToken`, while doing some research I found I should also set `initialstate`, so here is my 2nd version, but then this gives another error which is: `ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically`

```
// reducer.ts
export const INITIAL_APP_STATE = {
    dynamicComponent: {},
    fieldType: {},
    formCreate: {},
    formList: {},
    formTemplates: {},
    formPreview: {},
    formView: {}
};

export function getInitialState(): any {
    return INITIAL_APP_STATE;
}

// app.module.ts
imports: [
    // Version 1
    StoreModule.forRoot(Object.assign(reducerToken, reducers), { initialState: getInitialState }),
    // Version 2
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducerToken, { initialState: getInitialState }),
    // Version 3
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { initialState: getInitialState }),
]
```

Not sure how can I solve this now, I am just stuck here